# Minimum Spanning Tree with Additional Vertex

Tags: algorithm, graph

Does minimum spanning tree works for situation like this: If I want to go from A to B and I do not have to go to E, but the direct distance between A and B is larger than distance_AE + distanceEB, so I can go E first and then go to B. I'm not sure if the normal implementation of mst also works for this kind of graph. So if I want to find the mst of ABCD, but E is not included in this graph, how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you asking about the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're confused about the basic problem: what you've posted is a contradiction.  If `E` is not in the graph, then *by definition* dist(A, E) is undefined; for algorithmic purposes, it's `Inf` (infinity).

Yes, the MST algorithms work fine for this: the entire universe consists of (A, B, C, D).